# C# update object in nested objects

Tags: c#

I have 2 data classes:

```
class A
{
    public int n { get; set; }
}
```

```
class B
{
    public A obj { get; set; }
}
```

And in the main program, I create an B object and assign value to B.obj like this:

```
A a = new A() { n = 1 };
B b = new B() { obj = a };
```

It looks good until here,
but when I assign a new value to a like this:

```
a = new A() { n = 5 };
```

and then check `b.obj` again but the value is still `1` but not `5`

I know that objects in C# are reference type so I thought `b.obj` always refers to memory address of object `a`, but it seems it's not...

Is there any way to make `b.obj` always refer to memory of object `a`?

Comment: See, `a.n = 5;` would affect `b.obj` because `a` and `obj` both refer to the same object in memory, but `a = new A() { n = 5 };` points `a` at a new instance of `A()`. What is your reason for wanting to do this? P.S. Some people think [so] is "unfriendly" because we ask questions like this, but generally we just want to understand your use case better so that we can find a solution that works for you and fits within the confines of the language. I'm just trying to better understand your goals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fields of class, are they stored in the stack or heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565331/fields-of-class-are-they-stored-in-the-stack-or-heap)

Comment: There is a nested data structure with 4 layers: A() { B() { C() { D() { } } } }, and i want to update C.D to a totally new D instance directly, but not to assign value to it by A.B.C.D = new D() {}

Comment: Does adding a method on `A` work for you? So instead of `A.B.C.D = new D() { }` you could call `A.SetD(new D() { })`?

Comment: It's important to realize the difference between variables and objects. After your first two statements, you have created two objects, an `A` and a `B`. You have two variables `a` and `b` which refer to those to objects. But, your `A` object is also referred to by a property (`obj`) of your `B` object. Your third statement instantiated a third object (a second `A` instance). The variable `a` now refers to that new instance, but `b.obj` still refers to the original `A` instance - i.e., `a` and `b.obj` both refer to `A` instances, but different ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to simply add a method to `A` that simplifies setting `D`:

```cs
public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }

    public void SetD(D value)
    {
        this.B.C.D = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which will throw if `B` is `null`

Comment: @Fildor Indeed, but it's up to OP to ensure that all objects are instantiated. `A.B.C.D = new D() { };` (which is what it sounds like OP is currently doing) would equally throw if `B` is `null`.   If OP is using nullable reference types, they could declare `B` as `public required B B { get; set; }` and do the same in B for C, and the same in C for D to ensure they get set.

Comment: I just thought it was worth giving a heads up.

Comment: @Fildor Yep, you're right. :)